# Не открывается игра повторно

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

Есть папка из картинками и 3 файла, база данных(record, в ней 1 таблица,в таблице 2 столбца nicname и score), игра(racce) и меню к игре написанное на tkinter(menu) по замыслу в меню есть кнопка "Играть" по нажатию кнопки меню закрывается, и открывается игра, и аналогичная штука есть в конце игры, что бы игра закрывалась и открывалось меню, но почему-то при открывании меню 1 игра идет нормально, а когда в конце игры открывается меню еще раз, то при нажатии "Играть" меню закрывается и все

Вот код menu:

```py
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3

tk = Tk()
tk.geometry('350x400')
tk.title('menu')
db = sqlite3.connect("record.db")
sql = db.cursor()
db.commit()

lbox = Listbox(bg='RoyalBlue3')
lbox.place(x = 20, y = 100, width = 211, height = 150)

with sqlite3.connect('record.db') as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    lis = cursor.execute(f'SELECT score, nickname FROM bd ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 6').fetchall()
def LISTBOX():
    lbox.delete(0,END)
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        lbox.insert(END, lis[i])

def start_game():
    if ent.get() != '':
        name = ent.get()
        sql.execute("INSERT INTO bd VALUES(?, ?)", (name, 0))
        db.commit()
        tk.destroy()
        import racce
    else:
        print("Поле не может быть пустым!")

def exit_in_game():
    tk.destroy()

game = Button(text = 'Играть', bg='DarkGoldenrod1', command = start_game)
game.place(x = 20, y = 270, width =  150, height = 50)
Exit = Button(text = 'Выход', bg='DarkGoldenrod1', command = exit_in_game)
Exit.place(x = 20, y = 340, width = 150, height = 50)

ent = Entry(justify = "right", font = "14", bg='orange red')
ent.place(x = 125, y = 20, width = 215, height = 35)
nickname = Label(text = f'Никнейм:', bg='tomato')
nickname.place(x = 20, y = 22, width = 100, height = 30)

record = Label(text = f'Рекорды:', bg='chartreuse4')
record.place(x = 20, y = 60, width = 100, height = 30)

tk.configure(background='green3')

LISTBOX()
tk.mainloop()
```

racce:

```py
import pygame
import random
import time
import sqlite3
from os import path

WIDTH = 513
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 60
db = sqlite3.connect('record.db')
sql = db.cursor()
db.commit()

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
score = 0
score_chek = 50
speed_mob = 4
player_lives = 100

font_name = pygame.font.match_font('None')
def draw_text(surf, text, size, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_name,size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
def draw_game_over_text(surf, text, size, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_name,size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, RED)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

def mob():
    mob = Mob()
    all_sprites.add(mob)
    mobs.add(mob)

def l():
    live = Live()
    all_sprites.add(live)
    liv.add(live)

def walls():
    lin1 = line1()
    all_sprites.add(lin1)
    li1.add(lin1)
    lin2 = line2()
    all_sprites.add(lin2)
    li2.add(lin2)

class line1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10,480))
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center =  (WIDTH - 310, HEIGHT / 2)

class line2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10,480))
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH - 150, HEIGHT / 2)

class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_skin, (45,55))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2,HEIGHT - 70)
        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        global running, speed_mob
        self.speedx = 0 
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            running = False
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keystate[pygame.K_d]:
            self.speedx = 8
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT] or keystate[pygame.K_a]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP] or keystate[pygame.K_w]:
            if speed_mob == 15:
                pass
            else:
                speed_mob += 1
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN] or keystate[pygame.K_s]:
            if speed_mob == 4:
                pass
            else:
                speed_mob -= 1
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH - 160:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH - 160
        if self.rect.left < WIDTH - 300:
            self.rect.left = WIDTH - 300
        self.rect.x += self.speedx

class MM(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(lives, (25,35))
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH - 481, HEIGHT - 50)

    def update(self):
        global running
        if self.rect.top < WIDTH - 470:
            print('END')
            #running = False
        #self.rect.y += self.speedy

class Live(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        if player_lives <= 0:
            self.image = pygame.Surface((1,20))
            self.image.fill(GREEN)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = (WIDTH - 65,HEIGHT - 165)
        else:
            self.image = pygame.Surface((player_lives, 20))
            self.image.fill(GREEN)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = (WIDTH - 65,HEIGHT - 165) 

    def update(self):
        global pv
        if pv == True:
            pv = False
            self.kill()
            l()

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        a1 = random.randint(1,2)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(mob_skin, (45, 55))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        if a1 == 1:
            self.rect.center = (WIDTH - 190,HEIGHT - 480)
        elif a1 == 2:
            self.rect.center = (WIDTH - 270, HEIGHT - 480)
        self.speedy = speed_mob

    def update(self):
        global score, speed_mob, score_chek, running
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT:
            self.kill()
            score += 10
            mob()
        if score == score_chek:
            if speed_mob == 15:
                pass
            else:
                speed_mob += 1
            score_chek += 50
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if game_over == True:
            self.kill()

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')
lives = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 'lives.png')).convert()
player_skin = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 'player.png')).convert()
mob_skin = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 'mob.png')).convert()
background = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 'bg.png')).convert()
background_rect = background.get_rect()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mm = pygame.sprite.Group()
mm = MM()
all_sprites.add(mm)
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
liv = pygame.sprite.Group()
l()
mob()
li1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
li2 = pygame.sprite.Group()
walls()
player = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Car()
all_sprites.add(player)

pv = False
running = True
game_over = False
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update()

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,mobs,True)
    for hit in hits:
        pv = True
        player_lives -= 50
        speed_mob -= 1
        mob()

    g = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, li1, False)
    for j in g:
        pv = True
        player_lives -= 1

    g = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, li2, False)
    for j in g:
        pv = True
        player_lives -= 1

    if player_lives <= 0:
        game_over = True

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(background, background_rect)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    draw_text(screen, str(player_lives), 18, WIDTH - 100, 335)
    draw_text(screen, str(score), 18, WIDTH - 100, 100)
    draw_text(screen, str(f'{speed_mob}0'), 18, WIDTH - 50, 200)
    if game_over == True:
        draw_game_over_text(screen, 'GAME OVER', 100, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
        sql.execute(f'UPDATE bd SET score = {score} WHERE score = 0')
        db.commit()
        running = False
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()

import menu
```

Comment: там маленькая опечатка, там nickname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема из-за того что вы импортируете модули несколько раз. Так нельзя делать.

Вот один из вариантов решения проблемы:

```
import os
os.system('start ФАЙЛ_КОТОРЫЙ_НУЖНО_ЗАПУСТИТЬ')
```

Это даст команду консоли на запуск. (проверено на windows 10)

Comment: но ведь я импортирую то, что ранее уже закрылось

Comment: Это не имеет значения. Ведь файл который вы импортируете запоминает что его не запустили как основной файл, а импортировали.

Comment: понял спасибо большое